# Use JS or Jquery to insert rows, that include buttons, throughout an HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, rows

I'm trying to build an app that helps people list their expenses in a specific order. How can I allow them to add rows at specific points?

Starting with a simple HTML table like this:

```
<table id='exptable'>
<tr>
  <td>(date)</td>
  <td><input type='text' placeholder='Expense type (rent, groceries, etc.)'/></td>
  <td><input type='number' value='.00'/></td>
  <td><input type='button' class='addrow' value='Add Row Below'/></td>
  <td><input type='button' class='delrow' value='Delete' /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>(date)</td>
  <td><input type='text' placeholder='Expense type (rent, groceries, etc.)'/></td>
  <td><input type='number' value='.00'/></td>
  <td><input type='button' class='addrow' value='Add Row Below'/></td>
  <td><input type='button' class='delrow' value='Delete' /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

My "delete button" works fine with this JQuery:

```
$('.delrow').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

As for the insert button, They will ultimately be able to reorder the rows, so assigning each row a unique ID seems infeasible. Here's the atrocious code I have now:

```
$('.addrow').click(function(){
  $("<tr><td></td><td><input type='text' placeholder='Inserted Row'/></td><td><input type='number' value='.00' class='dollar ' size='8'/></td><td><input type='button' class='addrow' value='Add Row Below'/></td><td><input type='button' class='delrow' value='Delete' /></td></tr>").insertAfter(this.parentNode.parentNode);
});
```

**This DOES insert the row where I want it. However, neither of the buttons in the new row work.** Why not? Is there a smarter way to insert a row wherever you want?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/conditg/e45jd7ec/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your code that binds the click:

```
$('.delrow').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

Only works for those elements matching `.delrow` *that are present in the DOM when it is called*.  It will not work for any matching elements that are added later.

Instead, use a [delegated event](https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) where you put the listener on a shared parent and delegate down to the targeted selector.  Something like this:

```
$('#exptable').on('click', '.delrow', function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

...should be sufficient for your needs.  Also, I'd recommend ditching the chained `.parent().parent()` and replace it with something less fragile, like [`.closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/): `$(this).closest('tr').remove();`

Comment: Learning something new here jajaja. Nice answer!